# angularjs cannot read ng-repeat bind data - undefined

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

angularjs is boss but i'm not yet completely savy with it.

One issue i'm having is this;

basically i want the ng-repeat ng-model binding to be available to me inside a function within the view controller,

however - i think that the html is perhaps being loaded after the $scope can be populated so for some reason - the `$scope.someVar.id` variable is empty, unless i click the radio button bound to it... even though it is checked by way of a ng-checked condition. Visually the page loads and the option is checked. however the binding is not yet ready for me even after i attempt to do a few `$scope.$apply` in different areas. see below; I've managed a work around - but i want to stick with the angularjs method if it can be resolved....

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

HTML:

```
<span ng-repeat="someVar in someArr">
<input type="radio" 
   class="some-inputs"
   ng-change="updateOptions()" 
   ng-model="somVar.id" 
   name="option" 
   value="{{someVar.value}}"
   ng-checked="someVar.id == 1" 
/>
</span>

<span ng-repeat="someOtherVar in someOtherArr">
<input type="checkbox" 
   ng-change="updateOptions()" 
   ng-model="somOtherVar.selected_options"
   data-data="{{somOtherVar.data}}" 
   name="option" 
   value="{{someOtherVar.value}}"
   ng-checked="true == true" 
/>
</span>
```

AngularJS:

```
// all arrays are from http JSON get - data is working fine no issues with the data, only issue with the binding ng-model inside the ng-repeat 


.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


$scope.someArr = {};
$http.get('someURL?token='+auth.authtoken)
.success(function(res){
          $scope.someArr = res;                
        });

// OR if you want to see the data 
$scope.someArr = [ {"id":"1", "value":"a"}, {"id":"2", "value":"b"}, {"id":"3", "value":"b"} ]
$scope.someOtherArr = [ {"id":"1", "value":"a", "data":"X"}, {"id":"2", "value":"b", "data":"Y"}, {"id":"3", "value":"b", "data":"Z"} ]

   /// have tried this
   $scope.$apply;


   $scope.updateOptions = function() {

   /// and this
   $scope.$apply;


   // but this returns no value until i first click the radio button (someVar)
   $scope.selectedInput = $scope.someArr.id;

   // this works - and {{selectedInput is populated}}
   $scope.selectedInput = $('.some-inputs:checked').val();

  }

 })
```

Comment: Where is someOtherArr in your controller. Please add more details. provide more code.

Comment: someOtherArr is populated from http JSON response and its working fine that isnt the issue, but i'll update above for some idea of reference

Comment: Please do that so that we can understand code and find issue.

Comment: Yeah we need to see the model structure and array structure because it most likely something in that which is causing you issues

Comment: please see above i've updated based on structure of data -

Comment: you need to provide $scope.someArr and $scope.someOtherArr in order to use it in angular template

Comment: yes sorry the array is already set see above...

Comment: please check above - that isn't my issue the issue is regarding the binding...